# Index of the multiple of a group in itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let $m, n \geq 1$, prove that $[\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} : n\left( \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \right)] = \text{gcd}(m, n)$

When writing out the index as the cardinality of the quotient space, this looks like the third isomorphism theorem, but the $n$ doesn't allow this to work.

Also we could try to prove this with the first isomorphism theorem, constructing a homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow n\left( \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \right)$ with kernel: $\frac{m}{\text{gcd}(m, n)} \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\frac{m}{\text{gcd}(m, n)} = \lvert \mathbb{Z} / \frac{m}{\text{gcd}(m, n)} \mathbb{Z} \rvert = \lvert n\left( \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \right) \rvert$, and thus by Lagrange: $[\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} : n\left( \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \right)] = \frac{m}{\frac{m}{\text{gcd}(m, n)}} = \text{gcd}(m, n)$.

But none of these approaches seem to work. Any hint on where to start?

Comment: Your ideas are good! I think you gave up too soon trying to construct $\phi$! Try defining a surjective map $\Bbb Z \to n\Bbb Z$ and a surjective map $n\Bbb Z \to n(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$, and composing them.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, I tried that: $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow n\left( \mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z} \right), x \mapsto n\cdot x \mod m$. But I failed on finding the kernel:
$n\cdot x = 0 \mod m \Longleftrightarrow n \cdot x = k \cdot m$. Now I know $x$ has to be the gcd but I don't know how to argument that

Comment: OK. You already know what you're aiming for: you want the kernel to be $m'\Bbb Z$, where $m = m' \gcd(n, m)$. If you also write $n = n' \gcd(n, m)$, can you show that if $m \mid nx$, then $m' \mid n'x$? Then you know that $m'$ and $n'$ are coprime...

Comment: You can also make your third isomorphism theorem idea work, by the way! The key thing to realise is that $n(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z) = (n\Bbb Z + m\Bbb Z)/m\Bbb Z$. The fact that $n(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$ must be a quotient of some subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ is basically the "correspondence theorem".

Comment: Oh thanks! I see it now with the first isomorphism theorem. For the third, not yet, will need to look into the equality  $n \left( \mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z} \right) =  \left( n \mathbb{Z} + m \mathbb{Z} \right) \ m \mathbb{Z}$